# Debug mode giving different results from play mode and debug [Unity]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

So, I am relatively new to game development and Unity. I am making a Craps game and count the face values of dice. For the purposes of the what's necessary, I have `GameManager`, `DiceThrower`, and `Dice` scripts. These are all set up correctly, and as the title suggests, the game works during debug mode. It throws two dice, it counts the face values, and determines which state in the FSM to go to based on the value, if it's a comeout roll, or if its a point roll. But, as soon as I go to regular play mode, it *might* throw one or two regularly, but every other time it's rolled, it receives the value *before* the dice have stopped moving.

Here's what I have for clarity:

When a player clicks a UI button to Roll, this function is called (This is in the `GameManager`):

```
if (_currentState == GameState.RollingComeOut || _currentState == GameState.RollingPoint)
{
    _rollButton.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.gray;
    _rollButton.interactable = false;
    // Call a method in DiceManager to roll the dice
    await _diceThrower.RollDice();
    // Get the dice values after the roll is finished
    diceValues = _diceThrower.GetDiceValues();
    int diceSum = diceValues.Sum();
    if (diceSum != -2)
    {
        Debug.Log("Dice Sum: " + diceSum);
    }

    // Perform any logic based on the dice roll (resolve bets, etc.)
    
    // CALCULATIONS DONE HERE (For length purposes, I removed all the diceValue scenarios)

    _hasPlayerRolled = true;
}
```

What really matters here are the `_diceThrower.RollDice()` and `GetDiceValues()` calls. This is where it's differing from debug to play modes. The `RollDice()` line isn't waiting in play mode like it does in debug.

Again, for clarity, here is the code for those functions (both in the `DiceThrower` class):

```
public async Task RollDice()
{
    if (diceToThrow == null)
    {
        Debug.LogError("No dice to throw assigned. Please assign a dice prefab.");
        return;
    }

    foreach (var die in spawnedDice)
    {
       Destroy(die);
    }

    List<Task> rollTasks = new List<Task>();

    for (int i = 0; i < amountOfDice; i++)
    {
        Dice dice = Instantiate(diceToThrow, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        spawnedDice.Add(dice.gameObject);
        rollTasks.Add(dice.RollDice(throwForce, rollForce, i));
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(rollTasks);

    rollButtonClicked = false;
}
```

```
public List<int> GetDiceValues()
{
    List<int> diceValues = new List<int>();
    if (spawnedDice.Count != 0)
    {
        foreach (var die in spawnedDice)
        {
            if (die != null)
            {
                if (!die.GetComponent<Dice>().HasStoppedRolling())
                {
                    StartCoroutine(DelayResult(die));
                }

                if (die.GetComponent<Dice>().HasStoppedRolling())
                {
                    diceValues.Add(die.GetComponent<Dice>().GetNumberOnTopFace());
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return diceValues;
}
```

And, for more clarity, here is the `Dice.RollDice()` function from the `Dice` class:

```
public async Task RollDice(float throwForce, float rollForce, int i)
{
    _diceIndex = i;
    var randomVariance = UnityEngine.Random.Range(-1f, 1f);
    diceRb.AddForce(transform.forward * (throwForce + randomVariance), ForceMode.Impulse);

    var randX = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0f, 1f);
    var randY = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0f, 1f);
    var randZ = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0f, 1f);

    diceRb.AddTorque(new Vector3(randX, randY, randZ) * (rollForce + randomVariance), ForceMode.Impulse);

    await WaitUntilStoppedMoving();
}

public async Task WaitUntilStoppedMoving()
{
    while (!_hasStoppedRolling)
    {
        await Task.Yield();
    }
}
```

As you can see, it's a lot of waiting for asynchronous tasks. I assume this is where my issue comes from, but am not quite sure how to resolve it. I would very much appreciate a helping hand on this.